# Calculating specific building setbacks (front, side, rear) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, expression, analysis, building

I am trying to analyze building setbacks for a large area (multiple suburbs).

Setbacks needed:

- Front setback (minimum distance to street)
- Side setback (minimum distance to either side of the side property boundary)
- Rear setback (minimum distance to rear property boundary)

Available data layers are building footprint Polygon, Property Polygon, Road Casement Polygon, Road LineString.

Understanding that one can use shortest line expression to get minimum distance, however this will not distinguish which side the distance belongs to.

[image]

The property polygon has orientation info, I wonder if that would be any help in determining specific setbacks?

[image]

Comment: The front side is always the side closest to the street? How do you want to handle plots with multiple buildings on it?

Comment: Yes I think the front is the easy one. Good point about the multiple buildings, I am thinking embedding the property plot ID into the buildings within it and query the largest one?

Comment: Could you share some data to test possible solutions please?